# How does chrome extension require its own resources?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Does chrome extension retrieve its own resources(*js, css, images*) via an HTTP request, or with some other method? By saying "its own resources" I mean the resources that the *extension comes packaged with*. In other words, should I worry about including multiple CSS or JS files, or is it better to concatenate them?

I've been googling for the answer for past 5 - 7 minutes, but still can't find it.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? It gets internal files from the local package.

Comment: Are the internal files stored locally on user's PC, or are they stored on some remote google server? I'm trying to reduce the internal files loading time by reducing the HTTP requests that are required to load every file separately. But, if the files were stored locally on this kind of optimization would not be necessary. I'll try to explain differently if you still can't understand my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files inside the package are downloaded whenever the extension or app is installed and updated. This means you do not need to worry about resource requests failing, and you get offline functionality for free if you put everything you need inside the package.